# Import your own class in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, definition

I created my own class file in Matlab.

```
classdef Impact
%IMPACT Summary of this class goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        V       
    end

    methods(Static)        
        function Imp=Func(A)
            B=V*A^2;
        end
    end

end
```

It's possible to call the function `Func` like `out=Func(input)` instead of `out=Impact.Func(input)`. I hear about `import` command, but I don't know how to use it when the class is not inside a package.

Thanks very much in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Per the documentation for [`import`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) and the [Importing Classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/importing-classes.html) further reading:

`import Impact.*`

Will import all of the public static methods of `Impact` into your base workspace. Private static methods will be imported but cannot be called.

For example, with the following class definition:

```
classdef testcode
    methods(Static)
        function test
            disp('hi')
        end
    end
end
```

And the following commands:

```
 import testcode.*
 test
```

Returns:

```
>> test
hi
```

That being said, importing functions into your namespace arbitrarily like this is very much *not* a good idea and can easily lead to namespace clashes and confusion.

Per the documentation:

> Avoid using this syntax, as importing packages brings an unspecified
>   set of names into the local scope, which might conflict with names in
>   the MATLAB workspace. One possible use for this syntax is to import a
>   partial package name. Then when you call a function, you use a shorter
>   package name which does not conflict with simple function names. For
>   example, the `matlab.io.hdf4.sd` package has a `close` function, which can
>   conflict with the MATLAB `close` function.

---

You can also import *specific* static methods, which is a slight improvement on the above but IMO the caveat is still applicable.

For example:

```
import testcode.test
test
```

Returns the same as the previous example.

Comment: Simpler that I expected. I didnt' realise the possibility of import it as a package.

I guess in this context, the properties of a class doesn't make too much sense. Am I right?

Thanks very much!

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense.